# How to open and close new window with some more

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating simple app in which program load username + password from database (I'm aware it's stupid and I shouldn't use something like this in real life, it's only for testing/learning purpose).
If the name is not in the database, app should open new window and ask if you want to save the data in DB.
Now, the issue: the app works but I want to implement function to close the opened window after clicking on Yes (confirmation is displayed in the console).

Also, why do I have to use lambda here? If there's no lambda after program execution it automatically starts with commands specified inside the button click o.0
Is that related to interpreter and how it works? Any way to "normally" avoid this or ?

I've tried this:

```
class Window():
    
    def __init__(self, username, password):

        self.root = tk.Toplevel()
        self.root.geometry("300x200")
        self.root.title("New user")
        
        new_user_label=tk.Label(self.root, text="Save user in database?")
        new_user_label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        btn_yes = tk.Button(self.root, text="Yes", command= lambda: add_user_gumb(session, username, password))
        btn_yes.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        btn_no = tk.Button(self.root, text="No", command= lambda: self.Close())
        btn_no.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
  
        self.root.mainloop()

    def Close(self):
        self.root.destroy()
```

I'm calling this from another method/function:

```
def add_user_gumb(session, username, password):
    #check
    existing_user = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).one_or_none()
    if not existing_user:
        try:
            new_user = User(username=username, password=password, name=username)
            session.add(new_user)
            session.commit()
            print("User saved in DB!")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f' {e} while writing to DB!')          
    else:       
        print('User exists!')
    return
```

So, this code works but I lack knowledge of how to solve this within the code, like:
I also like the idea changing button Yes into close and deleting No button or something like that but I don't know how to do that - inside the if, while or how?
Can this window be closed from adding finally inside `add_user_gumb` method without declaring new value?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You need the `lambda` for the first button command because you have to pass arguments to `add_user_gumb`, but you don't technically need it for the second button because `Close` doesn't take any arguments - you could just use `command=self.Close` for that one (note the lack of parentheses after `Close` there!). That said, both `command=self.Close` and `command=lambda: self.Close()` will work.

Comment: line 14, in <lambda>
    btn_yes = tk.Button(self.root, text="Yes", command= lambda: add_user_gumb(session, username, password))
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'add_user_gumb' is not defined

Comment: There are no new window. You have blank window(garbage). Btw your code is working.